# Why does this not create a file?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to Python, Selenium, et cetera. I'm just wondering why in this context `test.txt` isn't created and written to when I run the script.

```
import scrapy
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = Firefox(executable_path='C:\webdriver\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.indiegogo.com/explore/wellness?project_type=campaign&project_timing=all&tags=&sort=trending')

show_more = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="text-center"]/a'))
)

while True:
    try:
        show_more.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break

filename = 'test.txt'
with open(filename, 'wb') as datafile:
    datafile.write('asdfsdf')

print(driver.page_source)
driver.close()
```

The issue is that the `break` seemingly breaks out of the entire script instead of just the `while` loop. In other words, if I move `with open` above the `while` loop, it does create the file.

**Why is that the case?!**

Comment: Make sure you are checking in the proper location for the file. Also make sure that the line datafile.write is executed by printing something above and below that line.

Comment: @serbia99 i'm definitely in the right directly. is the `break` in the `while` breaking out of the entire script and not just the loop? ok, figured it out. that appears to be what's happening

Comment: Any errors? Does `print` execute? I can spot that `executable_path` should be an r-string and you should pass byte objects to datafile.write.

Comment: @serbia99 how come `break` breaks out of the whole function and not just the loop?

Comment: @Anthony it definitely does not

Comment: @AndrewMorozko `break` def does not what?

Comment: break breaks the while loop. Not more.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre then why is the `test.txt` only created once i move that code above the loop?!@?!?!?

Comment: What probably happens is that you get an exception in `show_more.click()` (not TimeOut) and it bails out of the function. Try to catch `Exception` (all exceptions)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that makes sense. interesting. i'll test without `TimeoutException`

Comment: no, replace `except TimeoutException:` by `except Exception:`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre will that basically recognize any exception?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what r non-base exceptions and what r the chances of those happening? create the answer and ill mark it!

Comment: @Anthony I rollbacked your post. Don't edit with the solution. Edit for clarification only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here, the only reason why it wouldn't create a file would be that the `show_more.click()` call throws something else than `TimeoutException`. In that case the function/program is completely skipped.

You could catch all exceptions, and try to print which exception you're getting to refine it (it's not very good to catch all exceptions, sometimes you *have* to stop the processing)

```
while True:
    try:
        show_more.click()
    except (TimeoutException,Exception) as e:
        print(str(e))  # with that information you're able to refine Exception into something more accurate
        break

filename = 'test.txt'
with open(filename, 'w') as datafile:
    datafile.write('asdfsdf')
```

Comment: Yes, I don't know. This code above fixes the issue but needs to be changed when the exact nature of the exception is known.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't handled the right exception, as well as writing a string in binary mode. The only reason it would not create a file is if execution stopped during the while loop.

Comment: i dont care about what it writes, just whether or not it created the file. when i move the `with open` to above the loop, it works strangely